# React Routing 404 error on IIS when you hit refresh

Tags: reactjs

I did not find a solution for this issue yet I have tried various solutions but nothing works.
I have a react JS app which when deployed on the test server and you hit refresh on a page I get 404 error  message.
I have tried URL rewrite and this helped in navigating back to homepage but this does not resolve the refresh issue. 
Pls help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 19):

We can create a **web.config** file in project's root to fix this as well.

**web.config** file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what each line is doing and why it is needed? This did work in IIS and removing some lines makes it not work and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
<rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(docs)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
</rule>
```

I also ensured the path in my application's `<Route>` had the correct test server path, and this fixed it!

```
<Route path="/has/the/correct/testserver/path" component={testcomponent} />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are deploying first time make sure your have installed "URL Rewrite" and enabled it.

You can download extension from below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

and then create a web.config file and add below lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please restart the IIS and check the application it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add rules in your rewrite config. So that your base page is returned for every url in your react application.

```
<rule name="PageRefresh" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">                        
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/build(.*)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/script(.*)" negate="true" />       
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(YOUR_DOMAIN).com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:1}/{C:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whom who are using Nextjs, the must use `withRouter` like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

class Login extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    onClickHandler = (event) => {
        this.props.router.push('/newPage')

    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <p>Hello, {this.props.router.pathname}</p>
                <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Click me!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

My application is hosted on IIS 10. I tried making changes for URL Rewrite, but instead of receiving the 404 error, I started getting the 500 error (couldn't identify the cause).

So, I decided to use another solution. I edited the web.config file as shown below. This way, instead of returning the 404 error, the application will be redirected to the root of the application (similar to what we would do with URL Rewrite), and React Router will take care of the rest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```